# In UITableViewController textfield.becomeFirstResponder() not scrolling the tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

In `UITableViewController` have default property `UITableView` scroll when text field is selected, but it stop working if textfield selected using `textfield.becomeFirstResponder()`.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

textfield.becomefirstresponder() is not the same as being selected through uitableView. you'll have to select that cell as well

Comment: In this condition, I have disable table row selection.Even i implement self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath, but it still not working.

Comment: Do you have the scroll function inside tableview(didselectRowatindexpath)?

Comment: No, I haven't implemented tableview(didselectRowatindexpath) function.